# How extract NETCDF file for daily rainfall data for 60 years in R?

Tags: r, netcdf

I have daily precipitation data for 60 years that are in the netcdf format. how should I do that during 60 years? I know how should I extract that for 1 file (precipitation for the first day of the first year). but I don't know how should I do that for daily data for 60 years in R?

I'm a beginner in R

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add more details to your question. What libraries are you using in R? What have you done so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.